# UICollectionViewCell labels overlap each other in background color

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, swift3, uicollectionviewcell

I am new to iOS but can code in Swift 3. I don't know Objective-C at all.

I am learning `UICollectionView` and I have set of string arrays. When I am setting custom width to cell it doesn't works so well. the label overlaps one another. After that when I use flowLayout then it trims the label. Also the definite number of 5 cells in one row is fix.

Here's my code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

let reuseIdentifier = "cell"
var items = ["12", "2", "3221", "434", "52342","5646445646454464654646464", "bdvjsd", "adscfaaaw", "How are you?"];

@IBOutlet weak var flowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.items.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell

    cell.myLabel.text = self.items[indexPath.item]
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
    let a = (items[indexPath.item]).size(attributes: nil)
    cell.frame.size.width = a.width + 20

    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    // handle tap events
    flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 5.0
    print("You selected cell #\((items[indexPath.item]).size(attributes: nil).width)!")

}
}
```

Here's my screenshots:

[image: Screen appear on Load]

Finally I want output like every cell appears individually no overlapping and no trimming of label. If the width of label for "How Are you?" is x then cell containing that label must be of width x+20 (its just assumption) and that label or cell shouldn't overlap on any other cell or label

**UPDATE 1**

Here is the code what if I changed.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

let reuseIdentifier = "cell"
var items = ["12", "2", "3221", "434", "52342","5646445646454464654646464", "bdvjsd", "adscfaaaw", "How are you?"];
var x:[Double] = []
var tempItems:[String] = []
var flag = true

@IBOutlet weak var flowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.items.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath as IndexPath)
    let label: UILabel = (cell.viewWithTag(15) as! UILabel)
    label.text = self.items[indexPath.item]

    return cell
}

// collectionview layoutflow method. first this method call then other delagates method call.
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {

    let Labell : UILabel = UILabel()
    Labell.text =   self.items[indexPath.item]
    let labelTextWidth =   Labell.intrinsicContentSize.width
    return CGSize(width: labelTextWidth + 12, height: 35)

}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    // handle tap events

    print("You selected cell #\(indexPath.item)!")

}
}
```

And the output is same:

[image: Output After Update 1]

Comment: flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 5.0 comment this line and check it

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya trimming is not the problem. But overlapping is. I did trimming to show example that I have tried many ways but doesn't work

Comment: i'm little confuse about your problem just update your question with what you want actual output.

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya I have updated my question

Comment: func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
        if collectionView == coll_degree {
           
            let labelTextWidth = self.dict_therapist_profile.valueForKey("degree_acheive")?.valueForKey("degree_name")?.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as? String.intrinsicContentSize().width
            return CGSize(width: labelTextWidth + 20, height: 45)
}

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya What is coll_degree?

Comment: its my collectionview outlet beacuse i use 2 collectionview in single viewcontroller.

Comment: Can you provide same solution for my question? If possible?

Comment: ya sure. i give you solution with code .

Comment: Answer please..

Comment: i have answer but in swift 2.0 you have to convert that code into swift 3.0 .i give you suggestion only

Comment: okay please give me in swift 2.0.. Xcode will automatically convert it into 3.0

Comment: check my answer if any query about code then tell me .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In swift 2.0**

```
class MYVIEWCONTROLLER: UIViewController ,UICollectionViewDelegate , UICollectionViewDataSource , UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout{

  var items = ["12", "2", "3221", "434", "52342","bdvjsd","Hello","5646445646454464654646464", "bdvjsd", "adscfaaaw", "How are you?"];

// collectionview delegates methods.
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.items.count
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("invitecell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    let label: UILabel = (cell.viewWithTag(15) as! UILabel)
    label.text = self.items[indexPath.item]

    return cell
}

// collectionview layoutflow method. first this method call then other delagates method call.
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {

    return CGSize(width: self.findHeightForText(self.items[indexPath.item], havingWidth: self.view.frame.size.width - 116, andFont: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(14.0)).width + 12, height: 35)

}
 func findHeightForText(text: String, havingWidth widthValue: CGFloat, andFont font: UIFont) -> CGSize {
        var size = CGSizeZero
        if text.isEmpty == false {
            let frame = text.boundingRectWithSize(CGSizeMake(widthValue, CGFloat.max), options: .UsesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: font], context: nil)
            size = CGSizeMake(frame.size.width, ceil(frame.size.height))
        }
        return size
}
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){

    print("Selected item :\(self.items[indexPath.item])")
}
```

**In Swift 3.0**

**Don't Forget to look at class declaration. It extends UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout also**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

let reuseIdentifier = "cell"
var items = ["12", "2", "3221", "434", "52342","5646445646454446464", "bdvjsd", "adscfaaaw", "How are you?"];

@IBOutlet weak var myCollectionView: UICollectionView!
@IBOutlet weak var flowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let Labell : UILabel = UILabel()

    Labell.text =   self.items[indexPath.item]
    let labelTextWidth =   Labell.intrinsicContentSize.width
    return CGSize(width: labelTextWidth + 12, height: 35)

}

func findHeightForText(text: String, havingWidth widthValue: CGFloat, andFont font: UIFont) -> CGSize {
    var size = CGSize()
    if text.isEmpty == false {
        let frame = text.boundingRect(with: CGSize(width: widthValue, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude), options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: font], context: nil)
        size = CGSize(width: frame.size.width, height: ceil(frame.size.height))
    }
    return size
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.items.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell
    cell.myLabel.text = self.items[indexPath.item]
    cell.myLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow

    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    // handle tap events

    print("You selected cell #\(indexPath.item)!")        
}
}
```

Storyboard one label inside collectionviewcell. Use Autolayout.

[image: label constrain.]

**Output** :

[image: Output]

Answer (score 0):

```
func widthForView1(_ text:String, font:UIFont, height:CGFloat) -> CGFloat{let label:UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude, height: height))
label.numberOfLines = 0
label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping
label.text = text
label.font = font
label.sizeToFit()
return label.frame.width}
```

in heightForRow method

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
   let str = items[indexpath.row];
    let width = widthForView1(str,font:yourFont,yourHeight)
   return CGSizeMake(width, yourHeight)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Resizing each item of collectionView depending on length of the string:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize
    {
        let size = items[indexPath.item].size(attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18.0)])
        return size
    }
```

[image]